# Line-height on top only?

Tags: html, css

I have a site: http://starthumble.com/

The menu does a scroll-to-anchor effect on the same page. However, if you click "home" it scrolls and cuts half of the call-out text off. I've figured out that if I set

```
.companycallout h1 {
    line-height: 5em;
}
```

Then it scrolls properly. The only issue is that the h2 tag gets pushed way down. The only way I can find how to fix it is

```
.companycallout h1 {
    line-height: 5em;
}
.companycallout h2 {
    margin-top: -90px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Is this the best solution? Is there any better options? I haven't tested this cross browser yet (don't have access to it at the moment) so I'm not sure if it's compatible across the board or not.

Thanks!

Comment: The cutoff happens because the body has a `margin-top`, so its `.offset().top` (which the scroll plugin seems to use) takes that margin into account. Try setting `padding-top: 80px` on the body instead.

Comment: I didn't even notice the margin-top on the body. If that's the case, then pimvdb has the correct answer

Comment: That worked. I posted the code below. Scrolls fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your margin-top to padding top

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 80px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would return your CSS back to how you had it before.

Your solution is in altering the jquery plugin that you're using. More specifically the offset(). You can add a value to it. Here's more info on it:

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

[image]